# Herança Visual de Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, herança

Estou fazendo um formulário base com todos componentes que preciso para realizar um CRUD, e por exemplo, quando criar o formulário de cadastro de cliente, vou herdar a classe base e assim aparecer todos componentes básicos que preciso usar, até ai tudo bem, quando realizo essa herança os componentes aparecem como realmente eu queria, só que eles ficam como bloqueados, eu não consigo colocar mais nenhum componente em cima desse formulário herdado, existe essa possibilidade de pegar a herança da classe base e depois continuar colocando componentes extras ?

Comment: Boa pergunta , nao sou expert em montar guis em c# , mas nesta situacao em java eu criaria um panel como container na janela principal , herdaria este panel na outra janela e adicionaria outros guis nesta nova janela (no espaco que restou ), creio que consegue aplicar esta heranca em um container e nao no form inteiro no c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, para editar os controles adicionados no Form pai, altere as propriedades `MODIFIERS` desses controles para `PUBLIC`.

Comment: Bom dia Rovann, me desculpe a ignorância, mas onde eu encontro esse MODIFIERS para alterar para public ? No InitializeComponentes ?

Comment: Consegui amigo, alterei os modificados no InitializeComponent e deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: é uma propriedade do Form, você pode altera-las na parte visual também, na janela Properties do Visual Studio